# ReSharper NUnit3 - working with dlls without Copy Local duplicate

Tags: c#, dll, resharper

I run my test on visual studio 2017 on C# with ReSharper, our DLL appear on folder `.../Export/Release` - this folder is the Output path too

On folder `.../Export/Release/Plugin`s there are DLLs , those DLLs are duplicate on both folders by `Copy Local=True ( .../Export/Release/Plugins , .../Export/Release )`.

I want it to appear only on `.../Export/Release/Plugins`, so I change Copy Local to False on reference `IPDev.Plugins.Calibration.IEFD`.

But then ReSharper failed, and I get the following error message :

> "System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'IPDev.Plugins.Calibration.IEFD, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

I also tried to change NUnit3 to each of the following options:

[image]

Any idea how to resolve this issue ?